# Short story about an engineer coming back to an abandoned city where only the robots are working. I read it in an anthology in the 1970's

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This story is about a man who might be an engineer or engineering student returning to an abandoned city. He is trying to get civilization restarted but he must turn off the robot police who only recognize the authority of the mayor or governor of the city. This entails breaking into the mayor/governor's house where there is a master switch. I remember a scene at the beginning where robot bomber planes  open their bomb bay doors uselessly over the city, since the supply of bombs has run out. The author may or may not be Keith Laumer.

Comment: This classic Popeye comic may have been inspired by your story: https://lestresorsdelaflibuste.blogspot.com/2016/10/popeye-lile-aux-robots-1969.html

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is likely "[Dumb Waiter](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55981)" (1952) by Walter M. Miller.

The robots are futilely trying to continue a war:

> The bombers came out of the east. The ram-jet fighters thundered upward from the outskirts of the city. They charged, spitting steel teeth and coughing rockets at the bombers. The sky snarled and slashed at itself. The bombers came on in waves, occasionally loosing an earthward trail of black smoke. **The bombers leveled and opened their bays. The bays yawned down at the city. The bombers aimed. Releases clicked. No bombs fell.** The bombers closed their bays and turned away to go home. The fighters followed them for a time, then returned to land. The big guns fell silent. And the sky began cleaning away the dusky smoke.

Unlike everyone else who is moving away from the city, Mitch Laskell is cycling towards it.  He wants to reprogram the city's central computer (called "Central") to make the city livable again.

> The system had worked well. Apparently, it was still working well three years after the inhabitants had fled before the chatter of the Geiger counters. In one sense, Ferris had been right: a city whose machines carried on as if nothing had happened—that city might be a dangerous place for a lone wanderer.
>
> But dynamite certainly wasn’t the answer, Mitch thought. Most of Man’s machinery was already wrecked or lying idle. Humanity had waited a hundred thousand years before deciding to, build a technological civilization. If he wrecked this one completely, he might never decide to build another.

Mitch meets a young woman named Marta who is trying to get away with her baby after her husband killed himself.  (She initially steals Mitch's bicycle and shotgun, but gets arrested and Mitch needs to break them both out of jail.)  As they're escaping Marta points out the mayor's house and Mitch goes in to investigate

> The girl called suddenly from the library. "What's this thing, Mitch?"
>
> "What thing?" he yelled.
>
> "Typewriter keyboard, but no type. Just a bunch of wires and a screen."
>
> His jaw fell agape. He trotted quickly toward the library.
>
> "A direct channel to the data tanks!" he gasped, staring at the metal wall-panel with its encoders and the keyboard.
>
> "What's it doing here?"
>
> He thought about it briefly. "Must be... I remember: just before the exodus, they gave Sarquist emergency powers in the defense setup. He could requisition whatever was needed for civil defense—draft workers for first aid, traffic direction, and so on. He had the power to draft anybody or anything during an air raid."

They need to find the mayor's code, but then Mitch cancels all the useless rules the police were enforcing and adds only a few rules designed to protect what remains of the city's functions.

It was collected in Miller's collection [*The View from the Stars*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?38108) (1965) and in the Damon Knight edited anthology [*Cities of Wonder*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?34651) (1966).  You can read the original published version in [*Astounding*, April 1952](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v49n02_1952-04_Gorgon776/page/n7/mode/2up) at the Internet Archive.

Comment: Oh, I think I read this one (in a German translation) some 40 years ago. Wasn't the clue to the secret key provided by a wall clock whose hands moved in a strangely eccentric manner?

Comment: @EikePierstorff Yes, that's definitely this story.

Comment: Good catch, my first thought was one of Andre Norton's stories, Star Rangers.